# Linux Can't connect to MySql on Localhost

Tags: mysql, linux

I just installed MySql on Fedora 16 via YUM. The problem is that when I try to run mysql via

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

in the shell, I get the following:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If so, what should I do?

**Update**

Upon trying `mysqld start`

I get the following:

`bash: mysqld: command not found...
Similar command is: 'mysql'`

**Update**

The following command produces..

`ps aux |grep mysql
holland   1865  0.0  0.0 109232   888 pts/0    S+   11:11   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql`

What does this mean, exactly?

Comment: Usually you get that error if either your mysql isn't running at all, or is using some other than the default port (3306).

Comment: If it's not running, what should I do to run it? I tried running just "mysql" as root, and I get the same error. I'm guessing it's a port issue. Is there a way to find out what port it's running on?

Comment: If you just installed mysql, the server-daemon is probably not yet running. See abhinav's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to start the mysql daemon try `mysqld start`.
EDIT: To see if you've a mysql daemon running, check the process list.
`ps aux | grep mysql` or `ps aux | grep mysqld` should tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the problem:

As root..

```
chkconfig mysqld on
```

Following that you have the choice of doing either one of these three.

`service mysqld start`
`service mysqld stop`
`service mysqld restart`

More info found [here](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch34_%3a_Basic_MySQL_Configuration#A_Common_Fedora_Core_1_MySQL_Startup_Error).